# SQL query in MySql_Fetch_Array

Tags: php, sql, html-table, fetch

When I show this PHP on browser I couldn't get any value to table. My table is empty.

```
<?php 

    $sql = "select * from worksets where 'groupid'='$targetid'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    $kadro=$_GET['kadro'];

    if((mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)) {
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $groupid =  $result[0];
            $groupname = $result[2];
            $sql2 = "select flag from havestatus where kadroid='$kadro' and yid='$groupid'";
            $query2 = mysql_query($sql2);

            if((mysql_num_rows($query2) == 0)) {
                $sql3 = "insert into havestatus values('$kadro','$yid',0)";
            } else {
                $select='selected';
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><?php echo $groupname;?></td>
                <td></td>
                <td width='20%'><input type="checkbox" name="bev" checked="<?php echo $select; ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

If I change code in simple way like;

It shows some values and `unfunctional` `checkbox`.

I need to get some values from database and fill checkboxs according to 0 or 1 from database
and I have to insert all check box values with one form submit button to database as different rows for every check box.

```
<?php 

    $sql = "select * from worksets where groupid='$targetid'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

    if((mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)) {
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $groupid =  $result[0];
            $groupname = $result[2];
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><?php echo $groupname;?></td>
                <td></td>
                <td width='20%'><input type="checkbox" name="bev"></td>    
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

it is work after 'groupid'='$targetid'" to groupid='$targetid'"

Comment: change `$select='selected';` to `$select='checked';`

Comment: also you have not executed insert query.

Comment: what if you change `"where 'groupid'='$targetid'";` with `"where groupid='$targetid'";`

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: groupid='$targetid'" is working

Comment: you cant use normal quotes ('') for column name, that is used for variables like varchar. For column,table name you use other quotes -> backticks (``).